# Exporting Message Board Subscriptions to Excel

Tags: java, liferay

Original Liferay Forum Post: https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/46931970

I'm looking for a simple way to export the data stored in the Message Boards Subscription Manager to an Excel spreadsheet using Liferay 6.2EE. I need a list of each category & thread that each user is subscribed to. As far as I know, this isn't out of the box functionality.

The dynamic data list portlet has this as a standard action. Perhaps it's possible to transfer the list of subscribers there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to achieve your requirement without writing a single line of code, by using Liferay's Reporting capabilities explained here: https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/generating-reports-in-liferay-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-13-en.

Install the below plugins on your Liferay EE instance, and create your report as described in the above document:

- http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15099141
- http://www.liferay.com/marketplace/-/mp/application/15100467

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for and what appears to be much more. Thank you